# How to operate on a string while keep track of each char's score?

Tags: python-3.x

### Problem

I have a string and scores for each char in the string

```
text = 'text'
scores = [0.99, 0.98, 0.97, 0.96]
```

I would like to do many string operations to `text`, like `re`, `+`, `slice` or `split`, after do these operations, I want to keep correspond scores. For example, if I do a slice operation I want get `sliced_text` and `sliced_scores` as result:

```
sliced_text = text[0:2]
sliced_scores = scores[0:2]
```

Python3 has `UserString` class, for some simple operations like `slice` or `add`, it's very useful.

```
from collections import UserString

from typing import List


class ScoreString(UserString):
    def __init__(self, text: str, scores: List[float]):
        super().__init__(text)
        assert len(text) == len(scores)
        self.scores = scores

    def __getitem__(self, index) -> 'ScoreString':
        return self.__class__(self.data[index], self.scores[index])

    def __add__(self, other) -> 'ScoreString':
        return self.__class__(self.data + other.data, self.scores + other.scores)

score_str = ScoreString('Test123', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
a = score_str[0:2] + score_str[4:]
print(a.data) # Te123
print(a.scores) # [1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```

But `split` or `re` not work.

```
print(score_str.split('12')) # return string list ['Test', '3'], lose scores

import re
re.sub('123', '', score_str) # TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you overwrite the `split` method in your `ScoreString` class? Because if not, how do you expect it to return anything different than a normal `str.split` call. As for `re`, again how would you expect it to work without changing any of the functionality. It is designed to work with plain strings (except where otherwise stated)

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are trying to do in split function

```
score_str.split('12')
```

--> Here score_str is a class object which is inheriting UserString, so when you apply split function it will call the function of base class and you will get a normal output as str.split().

```
import re
re.sub('123', '', score_str)
```

--> Here when you are trying to implement regular expression, Then sub functions have arguments sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0), but here in third argument you are passing score_str, which is an object of ScoreString. That is why you are getting error.

If you will re-write as below,

```
re.sub('123', '', score_str.data)
```

It should work..
I hope this will help.